# How to take time measurements, Matlab

Tags: matlab, time

I have created a model on Matlab that plots the displacement of a moving vector using a force-based model, in a given amount of time.

I am now trying to figure out the time taken for the vector to be at specific locations, for example:

- The exact time at which the moving vector is in a specific location (on an x and y axis)
- How long the vector spends within a selected area over a period of time.
- How many times the the vector moves into a specific location.

Would anyone know where I might be able to find out how to do this? (Apologies if I am unclear, I am fairly new to Matlab and this website) Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Dan

Comment: Can you give an example of a moving vector? I'm a little unclear if moving refers to a change in magnitude and direction of the vector or whether the vector has an (x,y) location in addition to a magnitude and direction. Is there a real-world analogy?

Comment: To measure time fast and accurate use 'tic', save it in array.

Comment: you could use tic and toc command to measure time, see matlab documentaion for tic and toc commands

Comment: Are you trying to measure real time, like how many milliseconds have passed? Then use [`tic` `toc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html).  

Or are you trying to measure time in your model, like how to calculate time based on the forces in your model? Then you need to formulate some equations that describe this relationship.